# Xamarin UI Measurement

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm a UI designer working with a junior app developer.

We are working on an app I gave him the assets and there sizes using Zeplin app, he showed me the app and it was different than was design telling me that Xamarin doesn't use pixels or dpi but using a number without any measurement.

Is there any way to help him as a designer or something he can use to make the program use pixels or dpi.

Comment: `...a number without any measurement...` That is incorrect. Xamarin Forms uses device-independent units (DIU) which translate to a standard of "160 units to the inch" across devices, the docs fully explain it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05 I use content from various designers provided via Sketch, Adobe apps, etc... and do not have any problems, but you need to understand how Apple and Android handle sizes and how that translates to a common base in Xamarin, again the docs explain it.

Answer (score 0):

@Muslem Mohammed
I think as you are an UI Designer, you are aware that how to provide assets for native app development if not please check for below process.

You can provide Android Assets in the form of Mdpi drawable, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi.
And for iOS 1x, 2x and 3x same like native app assets.
And the developer place all those images into respective folder with respect to the platform.

Example: For Android you will be providing 5 kinds of images with same name respect to the folder I mentioned above.
sample.png for respective folders with the resolution, developer place those images into Android specific project.

Then developer place all images under resources and keep in respective folders.
For iOS also provide the images with same name and by applying 1x,2x,3x with sample below,

sample.png, sample@2x.png and sample@3x.png.

Then developer go to iOS project and place all ios images into Resources folder.

And finally developer will place the image control like below,

```
<Image source="sample.png" />
```

And this will show up the image in iOS and Android as well.